# Depth of a node in binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-tree, depth

I wrote the following function that returns the depth of a specific node of a binary tree.  Consider the tree here: If I ask for the depth of node 5, I should get an answer of 3, from the path 1 -> 2 -> 5.

It's not working; I get 0, even though I return the height from the function.

Here "data" is the value whose depth is to be found, and root is the root node of tree.  The initial value of height is 1 (the root node is level 1).

```
int height_target(node *root,int data,int height){   if(root==NULL) return 0;

if(root->info==data)
return height;

height_target(root->left,data,height+1);
height_target(root->right,data,height+1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  "it is not working" is not a sufficient problem description.

Answer (score 2):

Most notably, your recursive branch returns nothing.  Passing the height back one level isn't enough: you have to pass it all the way up the line.

You need to capture and return the maximum of the left & right subtree calls.

---

EDIT:  remove that last sentence ...

Thus, you need to return the value from whichever call (left or right) finds the desired node.  You didn't return anything.  Something like:

```
 ldepth = height_target(root->left , data, height+1);
 if (ldepth > 0)
     return ldepth;
 rdepth = height_target(root->right, data, height+1);
 if (rdepth > 0)
     return rdepth;
 return 0;
```

This will return whichever branch is successful in finding the desired node, and 0 on failure.

Comment: But why there is a need to return the maximum because all what i need to return is height at that particular layer.

Comment: The height at that p[articular layer *is* the maximum of the two calls.  If the right child is 3 deep and the left child is 5 deep, then you need to return a depth of 6 (5 + 1) to the level above you.

Comment: i think u misunderstood. i am returning the height relative to root node.           
consider the tree in the link mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteBinaryTree.html                                     I gave data as 5.So from root it is the 3rd node. It doesn't matter what is in its left or right child

Comment: Got it; thanks.  I'm editing my answer; first, I edited your question to help stop others from misreading it (as did the two of us who answered).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing anything with the value returned from height_target.

Presumably you want something like:

```
return std::max(height_target(root->left,data,height+1),
                height_target(root->right,data,height+1));
```

Comment: But i am returning value with the following code                                     if(root->info==data)
return height;

Comment: That will return only on the "layer" that found the data.  You need to keep returning that value all the way up the stack.  Another way of looking at it is  that there are some paths inside your function that don't return any value; your compiler should have warned you about that.

Comment: I agree with u that it will only return the layer on which it s found. but that is what i wanted. Lets say if root is 1. and left child 2 and right child 3. And if data is "3". Then we just want to return its layer only which will be 2. So shouldn't it return 2.

Comment: `return` only returns the value to the direct caller of the current iteration of the function, it doesn't magically escape some unknown depth of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get 0 as answwer because the condition 
  `if(root->info==data)`is never satisfied if there isn't a node with value equal to data. If you get 0 as a response it would be that the "data" you search in the binary tree there isn't.

Comment: No. I gave the value of data which was there in the tree but still got 0.

Comment: consider the tree in the link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteBinaryTree.html                                  I gave data as 5

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think i get it. Try with a function like this:

```
void height_target(node* root,int data,int height,int& h)
{
  if(root==NULL)
   return;

  if(root->info==data)
   h=height;

  height(root->left,data,height+1,h);
  height(root->right,data,height+1,h);

}
```

I think you supposend that there can't be two equal values in the tree

Answer (score 0):

> It's not working;

Here is one possible fix to your code: (updated - this code now compiles)

Summary - the last two lines of your code discard results during the 'decursion' (when recursion is unravelling).

```
int height_target(node* current, int data, int height)
{
   int retVal = 0;

   do {

      if (nullptr == current)
         break;   // 0 indicates not found

      if (current->info == data) { retVal = height;  break; }
      // found the node at 'height'; now de-curse

      retVal = height_target (current->left, data, height+1);
      if (retVal) break; // found data in left branch

      retVal = height_target(current->right, data, height+1);
      if(retVal) break;  // found data in right branch

   }while(0);

   return retVal;
}
```

Imagine your search item is found 5 layers 'up', so that highest recursion returns 5.

At layer 4, the data was not found, so your code then searched both the left branch and right branch.

With either branch, when your code returned (from layer 5) with the value '5', your code simply discarded the result.

---

In this possible solution, I tested retVal after return from either left or right. Now if the return value (from layer 5) is not zero, the function will return the non-zero value; eventually popping the value off the stack all the way back 'down' to the bottom of your recursion.

Perhaps a simplified call trace can illustrate:

```
 height_target (., ., 1);   // first call, data not found at root
 |  height_target (., ., 2);   // recursive call, data not found
 |  |  height_target (., ., 3);   // recurse, not found
 |  |  |  height_target (., ., 4);   // recurse, not found
 |  |  |  |  height_target (., data, 5);   // found! 'decursion' begins
 |  |  |  |  |
 |  |  |  |  returns 5  // height 5 returns 5
 |  |  |  returns 5   // height 4 return 5
 |  |  returns 5   // height 3 returns 5
 |  returns 5   // height 2 returns 5
 returns 5    // height 1 returns 5
```

First call now returns 5.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your understanding of what `return` does: it does not terminate all calls to the current function, it only ends the current iteration of said function and passes the value back to the previous stack frame.

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int args) {
    if (args == 3)
        return args;
    f(args + 1);
    std::cout << args << "\n";
}

int main() {
    f(0);
}
```

http://ideone.com/59Dl7X

Your compiler should have been warning you about the function not returning a value.

What you want is something like this:

```
static const size_t NODE_NOT_FOUND = 0;

size_t height_target_impl(node *root, int data, size_t height)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
        return NODE_NOT_FOUND;

    if (root->info == data)
        return height;

    int branch_height = height_target_impl(root->left, data, height + 1);
    if (branch_height != NODE_NOT_FOUND)
        return branch_height;
    return height_target_impl(root->right, data, height + 1);
}

size_t height_target(node* root, int data)
{
    return height_target_impl(root, data, 1);
}
```

Called as:

```
int h = height_target(root, data);
```

This returns a value of 0 if the node wasn't found or a 1-based height, with 1 indicating data was found in the root node.